# rviz crashing on startup with nvidia drivers installed

Tags: ros, rviz, visualization, nvidia

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get rviz running on my laptop.  It has an Nvidia 285M graphics card and I'm running the latest nvidia_current driver from the [xswat PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) (version 270.29) It has run before on this machine but recently stopped.

I get the following crash on startup:

```
[ INFO] [1299351402.417784177]: Loading general config from [/home/tfoote/.rviz/config]
[ INFO] [1299351402.418640732]: Loading display config from [/home/tfoote/.rviz/display_config]
The program 'rviz' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)'.
  (Details: serial 29 error_code 3 request_code 137 minor_code 4)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

How can I fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9303/rviz-crashing-on-startup-with-nvidia-drivers-installed/) by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is that the graphics drivers are installed but the kernel module is now named "nvidia_current" instead of "nvidia" which the system was looking for.

I ran "modprobe nvidia_current" and it worked.

I added nvidia_current to the list in /etc/modules and it now is loaded on boot.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2